# I'm newbie in c++, got unexpected error while <<operator Overloading. Could you tell me some advise?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

While doing some code practice myself I got some Error

**student.h** file

```
#pragma once
class Student {

public:
    Student() = default;
    Student(int id, const char* name, int score);
    Student(const Student& s);
    
    Student(Student&& other);
    Student& operator=(Student&& other);
    virtual ~Student();

    **friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Student & rhs);**

    void print();
private:
    int mId;
    char* mName;
    int mScore;
    size_t mSize;
};
```

**student.cpp** file

```
#include "student.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


... //bunch of constructors, override...

    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Student & rhs)
    {
        os << rhs.mId << rhs.mName << rhs.mScore ; // Compile Error: Cannot Access Student Member(rhs.mId, rhs.mName...)
    
        return os;
    }
```

The Error i got was i cannot access Student class member despite I declared it friend function in student.h

Strange to me, It compiled successfully if i declare `#include<iostream>` statement in `student.cpp` file like this

```
#include <iostream>     //change position <iostream> and "student.h"
#include <string>

#include "student.h"


... //bunch of constructors, override...

    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Student & rhs)
    {
        os << rhs.mId << rhs.mName << rhs.mScore ; //Compile successfully
    
        return os;
    }
```

So, why #include statement sequences are matters? i thought #include statement just copy-paste to my cpp file.

And it also compiled successfully when i declare `#include<iostream>` to student.h,

so when i include some #include things the Best-case is declare it to header-file?

Could you give me some advise?

I compiled my program in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: What was the exact error? The header files are included where they are required. In your header file, you're using `std::ostream` so you need to include its header file to make it visible for the compiler to see it.

Comment: you should include the complete error message in the question. Problem in your code is that `Student.h` needs a declaration of `std::ostream` but it doesn't have one. I'd expect a different error for that, but it would explain why changing the order of includes fixes it

Comment: i got error C2039: 'ostream': is not a member of 'std' and error C2248: 'Student::mId': cannot access private member declared in class 'Student'

Answer (score 3):

In student.h add an include for [`iosfwd`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iosfwd):

```
#pragma once

#include <iosfwd>

class Student ...
```

This will ensure correct resolution of the std::ostream symbol and recognize the ostream operator you defined as the one you declared as a friend.

The iosfwd header contains forward declarations of the symbols in iostream header, and it is defined for exactly this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ we must declare anything before using it.

So your problem is that you haven't declared `std::ostream` but you have used it in student.h.

An suitable solution is to `#include <iostream>` in the beginning of student.h, below `#pragma once`.

You can also put these before `class Stduent`:

```
namespace std
{
  class ostream;
}
```

This is called *forward declaration*.

Comment: Although your idea it right, we have `iosfwd` for that (other answer).

Comment: This works in principle. In the case of iostreams, the ostream is actually a typedef over `std::basic_ostream<CharType, TraitsType>`. There may be an allocator type in there as well - so the forward declaration is non-trivial.